# Do we need to use MappedByteBuffer.force() to flush data to disk?

Tags: java, performance, nio, blocking, synchronized

I am using MappedByteBuffer to speed up file read/write operations(). My questions as below:

1. I am not sure if I need to use .force() method to flush the content to disk or not. It seems like without .force(), the .getInt() can still work perfectly (well, since this is a memory-mapped buffer, i assume .getInt() fetches the data from disk, which means the data has been flushed into disk already.
2. Is the .force() method a blocking method?
3. Is a blocking method a synchronized block?
4. There is a huge performance difference with or without calling .force() method. What's the benefit of calling .force() manually? Under which situation should we use it? I assume without calling it, the data will still be written to disk behind the scene.
5. If we needs to call .force(), will calling it from another thread helps to improve performace? Will it corrupt the data because of synchronization problem?

   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
   import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
   import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
   import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("start");

    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test.map", "rw");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 2000000);

    int total = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i += 4) {
        mbb.putInt(i, i);
        //mbb.force();
        total += mbb.getInt(i);
    }
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(total);
    System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("stop");
}
```

}

Comment: Version of the JDK? (not that it's really changed that much)

Comment: I don't see what difference that would make.

Comment: None after looking at the Javadoc :-)

Comment: Is it faster to write directly to file than to write to a buffer, then dump the whole thing to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should call it only if you have extreme transactional requirements, i.e. you are implementing a database. getInt() reads from memory: the operating system pages the file into and out of that memory.
2. It is not specified.
3. Methods are synchronized if so specified. It has nothing to do with whether they block or not.
4. See (1). Data will still be written but at the operating system's whim rather than yours.
5. I doubt it, but see (2), and I doubt that you need to call it at all, see (1).

Comment: Gah, should've seen your answer coming in first, apologies for saying pretty much the same thing :).

Comment: I have a question, if I do not call force(), is there any io operation for that file when I call putInt or getInt?

Answer (score 5):

MappedByteBuffer.force() is **not** useless in Windows. I used "Process Monitor" tool from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 to monitor the file access. According to the logging, MappedByteBuffer.force() will immediately call Windows API WriteFile() in **Non-cached Synchronous mode**. The reliability should be similar as FileChannel.force() which will call Windows API FlushFileBuffers() immediately to write file. Therefore, MappedByteBuffer.force() is reliable enough for most kinds of usages. Tested on Windows 7 64bit with Java 1.6.0_24.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10941104)

Comment: I did not have right to add comment below a post when I wrote this post. This is why I created a new post.

Answer (score 2):

OK, take my answer with a grain of salt (I'm not a NIO expert)

1.) The `putInt(i, i)` will write to the MappedByteBuffer (mbb) which is in memory and the Operating System transfers that value into the actual underlying file (`test.map`) when it wants to.

Using `force()` tells the Operating System to transfer the data 'now' (which can be useful if you've got another process which needs to read from that file).

Your `getInt(i)` is reading the value from the MappedByteBuffer (mbb), if you use `force()` in the way that you are then you know that under the hood your file is in sync with that memory buffer).

Chances are you don't need to use `force()`

2.) Not sure, I *think* it is as the Java 7 NIO.2 stuff starts to allude to being able to do this sort of thing in a non-blocking manner.  I'm still researching that at the moment.

3.) These are two separate concerns.  I'd recommend having a look at Doug Lea's book :-).

4.) As 1.) states, force() will tell the OS to write 'now', else the OS writes when it feels like it.

Comment: I have a question that, when force is executing, any effect on  putInt()? , does put int has to wait force() to complete or does `force()` has impact on putInt()?

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6816049

force() is useless on Windows. Pretty scary bug.

Comment: In addition to Yao's comment/answer that the implementation was good enough for most users, the linked bug has since been fixed in JRE 7 build 118, current JVMs are not affected.